# Java/Kotlin JSON parsing improvement

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, kotlin

I consume an API which gives me this type of JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Start",
    "pid": "1",
    "position": {
      "data": {
        "x": "31",
        "y": "330"
      },
      "metadata": "empty"
    }
  },
  "metadata": "empty"
}
```

I have created the classes with objects with the same structure as the above JSON. I use the `retrofit` lib in Android which inside uses `GSON` for parsing the JSON.

My model classes would be like this:

**MResponse.class**

```
public class MResponse {

    @SerializedName("data")
    public User user;

    String metadata;
}
```

**User.class**

```
public class User {

    public String name;

    public String pid;

    @SerializedName("position")
    public PositionData positionData;
}
```

**PositionData.class**

```
public class PositionData {

    @SerializedName("data")
    public Position position;

    public String metadata;
}
```

**Position.class**

```
public class Position {

    public String x;

    public String y;
}
```

Now this works fine for me. But as you can see for every model I have to create a parent which will have the same structure just changes the child. This fact doubles the classes that I use for my models. I would like to ask if there is a better way to avoid all these classes.

I don't want to use inner classes. I was thinking that the guys that have done the JSON like this must have had a reason why they did it like this and also a way to make the parsing more easier.

Usually I was used to parse this kind of JSON structure:

```
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Start",
    "pid": "1",
    "position": {
      "x": "31",
      "y": "330"
    }
  }
}
```

And here it's easier if I would follow the solution above.

**EDIT**

Also any solution in Kotlin is welcomed

**EDIT 2**

Solution for Kotlin [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158379/java-kotlin-json-parsing-improvement/)

Comment: my comment here is having the classes is not bad it makes your code more structured but if you want easy way of serializing and deserializing your classes I can suggest a solution.

Comment: And I think it is also possible to avoid creating these data classes if you want

Comment: any solution is welcomed :)

Comment: And your question is ..? It seems like you want to skip mapping for the `data` and `metadata` fields, however still obtain the value under the `data` properties as if the given JSON were just `{"name":"Start","pid":"1","position":{"x":"31","y":"330"}}`?

Comment: No my idea is to find a solution that avoids me to create an extra class(that has data and metadata) for every model, but I want to have all the data that the JSON provides. In my opinion sounds like I am doing repetitive code and this way I have doubled the number of classes.

Comment: @Ultimo_m I don't see anything wrong of doubling, because you **cannot** do what you want with static mappings (how could one break the fundamentals?). You must have both values types along with their respective DTO types (your classes with `data` and `metadata`). Or try to switch to dynamic mappings based on dynamic structures like maps to hold both strongly-typed `data` and `metadata` (if it's possible with mixed typing though).

Comment: May I suggest to post it to [Code Review]?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I have posted there before posting here :D http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158379/java-json-parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the solution that I was asking for was quite simple in my opinion, I just didn't know it in the beginning.

Based on source code of `Retrofit` and some other related answers about `Java generics` this was the answer for my problem:

```
public class DataResponse<T, R> {

    public T data;

    @SerializedName("meta")
    public R metadata;
}
```

and this is an example how I can use it:

```
Observable<DataResponse<User, BaseMeta>> getUser()
```

For me this was the solution. If there are better solution out there, I am ready to accept them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your request is possible. If there is a solution, then it would just create intermediate classes that would do pretty much the same as what you're doing.

In Kotlin, I'd do the above like this. Feel free to even put it in one `.kt` file:

```
data class MResponse(@SerializedName("data") val user: User,
                     val metadata: String)

data class User(val name: String,
                val pid: String,
                @SerializedName("position") val positionData: PositionData)


data class PositionData(@SerializedName("position") val position: Position,
                        val metadata: String)

data class Position(val x: String, val y: String)
```